# Is there a way to change the URL text using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Let's suppose that I am writing Selenium tests for some public library website. The website has a login page. After logging into the website, I see a list of books. I can click on any of the links of the book titles. After clicking on a book title link, a summary of the book is dispalyed on the screen, and the url is something like:

> http://somePublicLibrary.com/Books/e6a9bb54-da25-102b-9a03-2db401e887ec?title=BookTitle

If I change the guid in the url to some invalid guid, then instead of displaying the summary, the page displays a message:

> No summary found.

I would like to create an automated test for this scenario.

I am trying to write methods like `changeUrlGuid()`, `getUrlGuid()`, etc. But how can I get the url text using Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the current url of the page loaded by using getCurrentUrl() method.

```
String url = webdriver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Then, all you have to do is replace old guid with a new guid.

```
int numOfChars = 36;
int posOfQuestionMark = url.indexOf("?");
String newGuid = "..."; // put new/wrong guid value here
String newUrl = url.substring(0, posOfQuestionMark-numOfChars)+newGuid+url.substring(posOfQuestionMark);
```

--Edit--

Now, load this new url in the browser.

```
webdriver.get(newUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, made my work easy, I had similar question, where I had to replace a part of code and then post a webdriver get request.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
 driver.current_url
```